# Split ultrawide monitor in 3 virtuals screens

Tags: nvidia, gnu-screen, split

For my work, I try to split my new ultrawide monitor in 3 virtual screens on Ubuntu (I don't want to use tile tools as gTile).
My first test using "xrandr" was OK when I selected "xorg" driver. But my monitor twinkle excessively to make me sick. So I selected "NVidia" driver and no twinkle. Good.
But now I cant' split my monitor using "xrandr".

Some informations:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Monitor: Samsung Odyssey G9
- Refresh rate: 240
- Resolution: 5120x1440
- Port used: Display Port 2
- Graphic card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070

Command to split:

```
xrandr --setmonitor VDP-L 1706/0x1440/1+0+0 DP-2;xrandr --setmonitor VDP-M 1706/0x1440/1+1706+0 none;xrandr --setmonitor VDP-R 1708/0x1440/1+3412+0 none
```

It's seems that "xrandr" doesn't work with proprietary drivers.

Thank's for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here:

```
xrandr --setmonitor A 2559/587x1600/367+1281+0 HDMI-0
xrandr --setmonitor B 1280/293x800/184+0+0 none
xrandr --setmonitor C 1280/293x800/183+0+800 none
```

The above works with the open drivers but not with nvidia drivers. Has anybody found a solution for that?